# Unable to read android spinner value

Tags: android, spinner

I am new to Android Development and just trying out various examples to familiarize.
I am unable to read and display the values from the spinner tool.

Checked out various examples from Stackoverflow and other sites but still getting blank values.

Kindly let me know where I am missing out.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Spinner wtype = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner htype = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    String w = weight.getText().toString();
    String h = height.getText().toString();
    String s1 = wtype.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String s2 = htype.getSelectedItem().toString();

    output.setText(w+h+s1+s2);
}
```

In the above code, the values for w and h get displayed where as the values for s1 and s2 do  not for all criteria...

It is just a simple BMI calculator. The strings.xml contains the following text.

```
<string-array name="weight_type">
    <item>kgs</item>
    <item>pounds</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="height_type">
    <item>metres</item>
    <item>feet</item>
    <item>inches</item>
</string-array>
```

By default, kgs and metres and shown. I click on the button to print the 2 default values but nothing happens..
I have tried changing the drop down values and click the button again.

Still no result !!!!

Tried with example from http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/
Still I am unable to get the result. The only difference was that I didnt use TOAST but tried to write the output to a TextView....

Could anyone post a working code pls !!!

Comment: Do you have items selected?

Comment: what kind of items are those ? what is your adapter like ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes. The items are getting displayed in the drop down and I am able to change them. But just that unable to fetch their value.

Comment: @njzk2 I am not using any onclicklistener events as such. Just a method onClick() to print out the details...

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Answer (score 2):

First of all findViewById has to be declared in onCreate() method.

Then like below get your Selected Item in a String:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) 
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               String s1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Then in your onClik method you only have to do is to set text:

```
String w = weight.getText().toString();
String h = height.getText().toString();
String s1 = wtype.getSelectedItem().toString();
String s2 = htype.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Just like S1 as above make another Spinner S2 Listener.

output.setText(w+h+s1+s2);
```

Comment: findByViewID does not have to be declared in the onCreate method. This is something you have seen frequently but is not a requirement.

Comment: @cbrulak very well but Its not a good practice to findViewById everytime the Button clicks.

Comment: @Sagar still unable to get the output.. I have tried the example from mykong site http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/ but I am unable to read the values of the spinner. Could someone post a simple working code for me?

Comment: Useful simple but have to know :)